# SLI of WLAN PCI Cards?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-card

I'm gonna upgrade my internet connection with an 300Mbps fiber.
My Wireless card can receive just 150Mbps, is there a way to put another card in a sort of SLI like in GPUs? Or I have to buy another Wireless card that is more powerful?

Comment: The real normal way would be to buy a more powerful card... however, with some tinkering, you might get two wireless cards to work together with Link Aggregation, see here https://superuser.com/a/1036199/368970

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @Twisty windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/32336-42-wireless-adapters#r8122147), the PC will use just one Wireless card to connect to the Internet.
So maybe you should buy a new and more powerful card.